# XML Get element based on attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

Can someone please help me. I'm new to XML and xElement.
How can I get number of men where year = 2013? The result should be 300.

I have this XML:

```
<company>
  <department>
    <departmentname>Dep 1</departmentname>
    <year id = "2012">
      <men>200</men>
      <women>1000</women>
    </year>
    <year id = "2013">
      <men>300</men>
      <women>400</women>
    </year>
  </department>
</company>
```

I have this code (not working):

```
XElement company = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath(myXML.xml));
var men = (from a in company.Elements("department").Elements("year")
           where (string)a.Attribute("id").Value == "2013"
           select (string)(a.Element("men"))).ToList<string>();
```

Comment: what about other departments!

Answer (score 1):

What about using XPath?

```
var xmldoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <company>
      <department>
        <departmentname>Dep 1</departmentname>
        <year id = '2012'>
          <men>200</men>
          <women>1000</women>
        </year>
        <year id = '2013'>
          <men>300</men>
          <women>400</women>
        </year>
      </department>
    </company>");

Console.WriteLine(
    xmldoc.XPathSelectElement(
            "/company/department/year[@id='2013']/men").Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want it from all departments

```
int mens=company.Descendants("year")
                .Where(x=>x.Attribute("id").Value=="2013")
                .Sum(x=>int.Parse(x.Element("men").Value));
```

---

Your query should be

```
int men = (from a in company.Elements("department").Elements("year")
           where a.Attribute("id").Value == "2013"
           select int.Parse(a.Element("men").Value)).Sum();
```

Comment: I would prefer to use xElement the way I have started. How can I do this?

Comment: @user2939293 Works on my pc... your xml is not in proper format..Attributes values must be within `""`

Comment: Yes, the values are within "" in the original file. I have changed it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement company = XElement.Load(Server.MapPath(myXML.xml));

var txt = company.Descendants("men")
    .First(x => int.Parse(x.Parent.Attribute("id").Value) == 2013).Value;
```

Not very robust but will do the job in your case and you should get the idea.

And with LINQ syntax rather than extension method:

```
var txt =
    (from c in company.Descendants("men")
     where c.Parent.Attribute("id").Value == "2013"
     select c).First().Value;
```

Comment: I would prefer to use xElement the way I have started. How can I do this?

Comment: The way you started? You mean using LINQ syntax rather than extension methods?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys. I used this and it's working
Thank you for your help!

```
 XElement com = (from p in company.Elements("department")
                                    where (string)p.Element("departmentname").Value == "Dep 1"
                                    select p).First();



    var men= (from a in com.Elements("year")
                              where (string)a.Attribute("id") == "2013"
                              select (string)(a.Element("men"))).ToList<string>();
```